# Can't link Firebase project to Google Play

Tags: firebase, google-play-console

I have 4 projects in Firebase. These projects are Google Play apps, so all of them (except for this new one) are linked to their Firebase project.

To make this integration, I go to project configuration and create the Android app. This has the debug and release SHA-1 but also the package name. When this is complete, in the integrations tab, Google Play should be linked.

Not sure why, the last one I created says that "all the apps for this project are linked to Google Play in other Firebase projects".

I checked the rest of the Firebase project and all of them seem to be fine.

What might be the problem?